# How to change the features imporance in Xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have an imposed feature that scores 0 in the XGBOOST feature importance score. However, I would like my model to consider it. Is there a solution that allows to edit (brute force) feature importance? Otherwise, is there any theory that can address my problem ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The model has already considered them in fitting. That is how it knows how important they have been in the first place. Feature importance values are the model's results and information and not settings and parameters to tune. You may use them to redesign the process though; a common practice, in this case, is to remove the least important features and re-run (feature selection).

Comment: "The algorithm" excluded them for a reason. They give him the least amount of information. You can try make your model deeper (incease "max_depth" hyper-parameter), as adding more splits might add them, But they'll still have the lowest Importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the model you are using, XGBoost chooses the feature importance when fitting to improve the score.

You may use another model such as KNN. If you use `StandardScaler` on your features, they will all have the same importance even if the correlation is really bad. Then, you can change the standard deviation of any feature to increase or decrease its importance.

You are more than likely to reduce the performance of your model but if you absolutely want a feature to be taken into account, I think it is a good way to do.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm has actually considered your feature in its calculations. If it has found an importance of 0, that means this feature has little (or nothing) to do with the variable you're trying to predict. In other words, this feature has not given any information to help the algorithm make a decision (or splits in the case of the XGBoost).

Try to look at this variable again and think: why do you want to force it as a predictor? Maybe it is just not the right feature to consider. If the importance is zero, you may also want to double check if you have implemented the feature correctly.

As some of the other remarks have stated, you can try to deepen your trees, hoping that it will find some useful connection between your feature and the target.